# How to use simple form Nested in a FORM who runs at server Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've applied Master page to my existing application.Master Page has form control who runs at server . My page have  multiple forms in which some forms runs at server and some doesn't runs at server . How can I Handle this Situation :

**Master Page :**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

**Content Page :**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<form action="VersionControl_11g.aspx" name="Form1" id="Form1" >
...
</form>
   <form runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
...
</form>
<form action="VersionControl_11g.aspx"  name="Form2" id="Form2">
...
</form>

 <form runat=server >
...
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

I have tried closing the form tag in the begining of Content page then again opened the form tag where required in the content page but more than one form with runat=server attribute are not allowed .

I want the way where I could use simple Forms without runat server attribute nested inside the Form exists in Master page .

As due the huge functionality of the page , I can not modify the overall structure of page.

Please Help me :(

Thanks

Comment: Nested forms are not allowed. You need to get either rid of the form in your master page or the forms in your aspx page.

Comment: Is there any way to use multiple forms with runat server attribute on the same page?

Comment: From memory, you can create a custom form class that inherits from System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm. This custom class can have a boolean RenderFormTag property which you can use to toggle custom form on and off - the idea being that you can turn on/off each form as you need to use it...

Comment: @IrishChieftain at the same time , both of these types of forms are being used :(

Comment: I've done it for two forms on same page but it's a huge hack. Change your design to avoid this scenario is my best advice. And no, not at SAME time.

Comment: Why you wanna use multiple forms, instead of using multiple forms, create user controls and use them within one form, it will be look like you are using multiple forms and will definitely address your issues of using nested forms. [Have a look here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET)